# Microsoft Office 365 problem cannot open a blank excel document

Tags: excel, windows, office365, powerpoint

Ever since I factory resetted my computer(Windows 11, don't know if this information is required but I am providing it in case it is) I have not been able to open up any kind of Microsoft Office 365 app files, such as Excel, PowerPoint, MS Word, ect. This includes not being able to open any files, AND creating any files, like Workbooks, Word documents, PowerPoint Presentations, ect.

I just tried to open Microsoft Office 365, then choose Excel, then click on Blank Workbook.[image: Office 365 homepage] However, even after clicking on "Blank Workbook", nothing happened.[image: Excel\Blank Workbook] I would be really happy if anyone could solve this problem as Excel, Word and Powerpoint are all really nessassary for my work.

Comment: If you have done a factory reset then you may need to re-register or login to Microsoft 365. But this question is really beyond the scope of a programming forum. I suggest you use on of the Microsoft forums.

Comment: @OldBoy I have already logged in to Microsoft 365. But, thank you for your suggestion. I will post this question to the Microsoft forums.